# html element on every blog page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a tab overlay on my custom front page. the tab head extends from the edge of the screen and when clicked, the tab body extends into the frame. Is there a php template page into which I can import this html/javascript code so that my tab displays on every blog page and post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most themes have a [`header.php` and a `footer.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Basic_Templates) which load on every page. You can put your code in there, or, better, build a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). You can also hook into [`wp_footer`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your the theme that you use, but assuming the theme follows [WP theme conventions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_File_Checklist) I would recommend sticking your code in the header.php file - most page and post templates call wp_head() so your code should show up in most if not all blog page and post if you stick it in the header.